# Saving array of remote images in server

Tags: php

So, I have this code, but didn't worked

```
<?
foreach($itemlist as $item) {
    $imagepic = $item['mainpictureurl'];
    for($k=0;$k<count($imagepic);$k++){
            echo $imagepic++;
            echo "<br>";
            $isok=copy($imagepic[$k] , $_SERVER . dirname(__FILE__).'/test/item_'.($k+1).'.jpg');
            if($isok==true){
                echo' success!';  
            }else{
                echo ' Fail';  
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I kept on getting this error

```
Warning: copy(h) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/decultur/public_html/shop/templatescustom/main/itemlist.html on line 111
Fail
```

What am I missing, please tell me

Comment: obviously, that file does not exist, try checking the path. A side question: an array (considering that you iterate it) or a numerical value (considering that you increment it)

Comment: also a small note: it is generally recommended to avoid the short open tags (http://jm2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) because of the conflicts that they can generate.. most server have this option disabled (at least that's what I noticed)

Answer (score 0):

[`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is an array, so your path is getting made as something starting with the path `Array`. You need to find the actual value you're looking for and use the proper index for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `$_SERVER` array as a whole which will result (after casted to string) in `Array`. You should use `$_SERVER['your_var']`
Take a look at the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php